# can use yii2 DepDrop::widget without model?

Tags: yii2

all developer `kartik\DepDrop` widget The ability to use without model

My code this but error

```
use kartik\widgets\DepDrop;


<?php echo DepDrop::widget([
    'options' => ['id'=>'customer-city'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
       'depends  => ['province'],
       'placeholder => 'select ...',
       'url' => Url::to(['/site/city'])
    ]
]);  ?>
```

I use this code for show dropdown without lable

Comment: Which type of error you are getting?

Comment: Showing your code and mentioning that "there's an error" is about as descriptive as taking a picture of your car and asking a mechanic why it won't start.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for it you need set the attribute `name`:

```
<?php echo DepDrop::widget([
    'name' => 'city',
    'options' => ['id'=>'customer-city'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
       'depends'  => ['province'],
       'placeholder' => 'select ...',
       'url' => Url::to(['/site/city'])
    ]
]);  ?>
```

Comment: minor syntax error.
quotes missing at depends and placeholder